# Как получить символ табуляции, пробела по их коду?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такой код. Там где одинарные кавычки нужно вставить символ табуляции.
Однако если вставлять его напрямую то текстовые редакторы удалят табуляцию и вставят пробелы вместо неё.

```
TRIM(BOTH  '    ' FROM `name`)
TRIM(BOTH  символ_по_коду(9) FROM `name`)
```

Comment: Используйте CHAR(9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символ табуляции можно вставить так `'\t'`